# Filling WPF DataGrid in C# with a Dictionary <String,String>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to fill my DataGrid in C# with a Dictonary.
I already set my Dictionary as the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.
But no data is displayed...
I also set AutoGenerateColumns to true.
Where is the mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to specify the columns explicitly:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it with `TwoWay` mode? Cause when I'm trying to make it, there occurs exception: _System.InvalidOperationException: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Key' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]'.'_

Comment: @Snail, no, that won't work. The `Key` and `Value` properties of a `KeyValuePair` are read-only. You would need some kind of adapter between the dictionary and the UI.

Answer (score 9):

The following works for me. You dont need to set columns explicitly.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DictionaryDataGridDemo.SingleDictView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DictionaryDataGridDemo"
        Title="SingleDictView"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SingleDictViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
            <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>-->
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DictionaryDataGridDemo
{
    public class SingleDictViewModel
    {
        public Dictionary<double, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }

        public SingleDictViewModel()
        {
            MyDictionary = new Dictionary<double, string>();
            MyDictionary.Add(100, "A100");
            MyDictionary.Add(200, "B200");
            MyDictionary.Add(300, "C300");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that AutoGenerateColumns is set to False.

```
    <DataGrid
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```