# How can I include a dictionary in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a dictionary

```
private Dictionary<int, data> mdata = new Dictionary<int, data>();
```

I would like to edit the Dictionary in the UI.

I think using with a DataGridView is a possibility.

How can I put the data from the dictionary into the DataGridView and after editing back into the dictionary?

Comment: What UI framework? What data grid exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204423/filling-wpf-datagrid-in-c-sharp-with-a-dictionary-string-string

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'datagird'. There are DataGrids and GridViews and DataGridViews, depending on what you do. Winforms? DataGridViews ! Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928567/using-a-dictionary-in-a-propertygrid)?

Comment: UI is User Interface

Comment: And its a dataGridViews

Comment: Yes, excactly a Winforms-Project

Comment: [DataGridView bound to a Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854953/datagridview-bound-to-a-dictionary) suggests using a DGV may not be the best way. Have you looked at the PropertyGrid answer suggested by @TaW?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView.DataSource =  (from d in dictionary
                             orderby d.Value
                             select new
                              {
                               d.Key,
                               d.Value
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: That's not going to write the edited values back, though.