# How to bind dynamic data to data grid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the below class as my DataModel:

```
public class InspectorOutput
{
    string m_SymbolName;
    // Each string is a column name with its value in double
    List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> m_ListPrices = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

    public string SymbolName
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SymbolName;
        }

        set
        {
            m_SymbolName = value;
        }
    }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> ListPrices
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ListPrices;
        }

        set
        {
            m_ListPrices = value;
        }
    }
    public void addResult(string strResultName, double nResult)
    {
        ListPrices.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(strResultName, nResult));
    }
}
```

In my xaml window data grid is defined as below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridStockData">
                </DataGrid>
```

Later on, in my mainwindow I have the below code:

```
    private void runProfile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<InspectorOutput> listOutput = null;
        Profile.Profile objProfile = null;
        Inspector.InspectorManager objInspectorManager = null;
        try
        {
            // Some code here which makes a profile out of user input in objProfile
            objInspectorManager = new Inspector.InspectorManager();
            // Calculate data based on given profile
            listOutput = objInspectorManager.startInspector(objProfile);
            // Show calculated data
            gridStockData.ItemsSource = listOutput;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getInstance().error(ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

The problem is as follows:

- I have stock data for 10 companies.
- Each company has a symbol name.
- Calculated data for each symbol is stored in m_ListPrices where each key is a column name and each value is a cell value

  - Note: Columns are not known until run time(ie: Based on user's selected algorithm column names and numbers may vary).

I have a calculator class that runs user selected algorithms. Each algorithm has it's own output which stores it in above data model.
How could I possibly bind this DataModel to a DataGrid in WPF?

Currently above code gives me the following output:

[image: Grid Output]

Comment: From looking at the image you provided, then I assume you meant Row* and not column when you said: "_// Each string is a column name with its value in double_"

Comment: Consider creating a [row details template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) specific to each of the user-selected algorithms.  Create a [template selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to display the correct template based on the selected row.

Comment: Or you can do a generic data template that binds to dictionary.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204423/filling-wpf-datagrid-in-c-sharp-with-a-dictionary-string-string) is a SO example.

Comment: Thank your for your quick response.
I found row details quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got over the problem:
I create a DataTable as data source for my data grid which is filled with columns inside the dictionary.

```
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Columns.Add("Symbol Name", typeof(string));

            // Add columns
            foreach (InspectorOutput item in listScenarioOutput)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in item.ListPrices)
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add(entry.Key, typeof(double));
                }
                break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listScenarioOutput.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
                row.SetField(0, listScenarioOutput[i].SymbolName);
                int j = 0;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in listScenarioOutput[i].ListPrices)
                {
                    row.SetField(++j, entry.Value);
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            gridStockData.ItemsSource = tbl.DefaultView;
```